# Change border color of a div conditionally angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have these two arrays :

> Original Array :

```
$arr_1=['disappear','rising','filled','decades];
```

> User Array:

```
$arr_2=['disappear','filled','filled','decade]; 

this.indexesAttention=[];
$arr_1.forEach(x=>{   
      //concat two arrays
       this.indexesAttention=[...this.indexesAttention,
                                    ...this.checkValue(x)]
 });

 checkValue(variable:string):number[]
 {
     
    return this.arr_2
    .map((x,index)=>x.trim()==variable.trim()?index:-1)
   .filter(x=>x!=-1) //only want the index>>-1
 }
```

These should return the matching indexes in this case it should return `[0,2]` indexes because they are matching but in my case it is returning `0,2,1,3`

```
 [ngStyle]="(indexesAttention.indexOf(i)<0) ? {'border-color':'red','color':'red'} : show_answer === false ? {'border-color': 'black','color':'black'} : {'border-color': 'green','color':'green'}"
```

Any solution to resolve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  arr1 = ['disappear','rising','filled','decades'];
  arr2 = ['disappear','filled','filled','decade'];

  constructor(){
    const a = this.arr2.map((e,k) => {
      const i = this.arr1.indexOf(e);
      return k == i?i:-1;
  }).filter(e => e != -1)        
    const rs = [...new Set(a)]; //output [0, 2]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but why output [0,2,2] it should be only `0,2`

Comment: In the arr2 the "filled" word is repeated two times

Comment: You can use new Set() to ensure unique values in final array

Comment: @NathashKumar But i want in second array only `disapperar and filled` are matched so it should return those match index i.e. `0 and 2`

Comment: Please check code now, i have updated to give unique values

Comment: @NathashKumar : I tried this array `(4) ['decade', 'disappear', 'alarming', 'rising']`
`(4) ['disappear', 'decade', 'rising', 'alarming']` but getting this result
`results  [1, 0, 3, 2]` this should return `blank` array

Comment: Please check the updated map function block in the above code, hope this will work for you